# Mpdf - Render table with css

Tags: mpdf

I've been trying to create a pdf of a mediawiki page with mpdf and wverything is fine, except all tables that are not correctly rendered.

I have isolated the problem and to reproduce it I create a simple example that shows what Im facing in there..

When trying to render the following table:

```html
<style>
   .wikitable tbody tr th, table.jquery-tablesorter thead tr th.headerSort, .header-cell {
   background: #009999;
   color: white;
   font-family: "Courier New", Courier, "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Typewriter", monospace;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 13pt;
   }
   .wikitable, table.jquery-tablesorter {
   box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   }
   .tabela, .wikitable {
   border: 1px solid #A2A9B1;
   border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   .tabela tbody tr td, .wikitable tbody tr td {
   padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
   border: 1px solid #A2A9B1;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   .config-value {
   font-family: "Courier New", Courier, "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Typewriter", monospace;
   font-size:13pt; 
   background: white; 
   font-weight: bold;
   }
</style>
<table class="wikitable tabela">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="4"> SAP</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> Servidor SAP </td>
      <td class="config-value" colspan="3"> 10.18.254.71</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> Instance Number</td>
      <td class="config-value"> 00 </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> System ID</td>
      <td class="config-value"> 500</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> Usuário</td>
      <td class="config-value"> 234234  </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> Senha</td>
      <td class="config-value"> dev@2543</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> Depósito</td>
      <td class="config-value"> AWS </td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">  Centro </td>
      <td class="config-value">  001</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"> Sistema de Depósito</td>
      <td colspan="3" class="config-value">  WHY</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">SAP Router</td>
      <td colspan="3" style="&quot;text-align:left;" class="config-value"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

we get the following result:
[mpdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBo7e.png)

As the browser render as:

[Table rendered by browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y223r.png)
The php code is:

```html
<?php
   
require_once __DIR__ . '/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php'; 
 
$mpdf =new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
 'mode' => 'utf-8' 
]); 
$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 0;
$mpdf->keep_table_proportions = true;
 
$html = file_get_contents('c:\TMP\html.html');

$mpdf->WriteHTML( $html );
$mpdf->Output( 'saida.pdf', 'F' );
```

How to make mpdf render the table correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue aplying inline style using https://github.com/MyIntervals/emogrifier.